# How to use python to control hotkey in excel (pyautogui)

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, pyautogui

```py
import win32com.client as win32
import pyautogui

file_path = r'my path'

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)

sheet = wb.Sheets('Data')

sheet.Columns(2).Insert()

sheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = 'PeriodCode'

last_row = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(win32.constants.xlUp).Row

last_cell_periodcode = sheet.Cells(last_row, 2)

formula = f'=VLOOKUP(A2, Reference!$E:$F, 2, 0)'
sheet.Cells(2, 2).Formula = formula

#locate at specific cell to perform function by pyautogui
specific_cell = sheet.Cells(1, 1)

pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Down')
pyautogui.hotkey('Right')
pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Shift', 'Up')
pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'd')

wb.Save()
```

I have tried the above script to fill down the formula, however by using above script, I do not get the expected output I want. It does not perform highlight cell and fill down.

Comment: Since you have the Excel application open and under your control, why are you wasting time hacking around with pyautogui?  Just do the operations yourself.  Your COM operations do not have any effect on the cursor, so you have no idea where the cursor is when you do the Ctrl-Down.

Comment: I intend to fully automate data processing and data wrangling progress by a python script

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant.  You have the application's full API available.  Don't mix that and fake keystrokes.